# Ceph for small files?

Tags: storage, ceph

Currently I have 6 dedicated servers in a data center. Two Servers are Mailservers running exim and dovecot (Maildir) and 4 Webservers. Each Server has two 3TB HDDs.

My current problem is, that we now have a video production team and they need storage. Probably scalable storage. Currently they have to look, on what server they have enough free space. And that's what I want to solve.

So my idea is to use Ceph for two things: First of all to create a Failover Solution for the Mail- and Webservers. So if a server fails, the Load Balancer just switch to another server where the files are also available.

And the second one is that I get a scalable storage for the video files and the video team doesn't have to care about file size. They have their file structure on a single machine and can work with their files on this "machine". And if I need more storage, I just rent another dedicated server and add it to the "cluster".

That's why I'd like to ask, if Ceph is a good idea for this. Or do you have another better suggestion?

Comment: If you want real scalability, isn't cloud storage an option?

Comment: Because of the cost. The drives are built into this server we really need. So why waste it instead of using this drives? We have 6x2x3TB, it's 36TB of storage, ok 18 TB I have a redundancy. This kind of storage wold cost me 100€ per Month in a cloud.

Comment: Great question, and although I can't give an answer, I believe Gluster (in particular) has to be tuned to the workload, so Ceph may be similar in this regard. E.g., with fewer, larger video files, throughput may be more important that more, smaller mail files, where latency may be more important. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=61HDVwttNYI (Good luck!)